# Separate global basic styles from every page using webpack in vue-cli3

Tags: vue.js, webpack, sass, vue-cli-3, chunks

I'm using Vue-cli3.x, which is a multiple-pages project. I'm using SCSS in this project and separating the global basic styles with **loaderOptions** as following:

[image]

The styles relations like this: **basic styles --->  components' styles ---> pages' styles**

But after I building my project, I found my CSS files include basic styles more than once.
EX: *dashboardAirLeft page* includes *chunk-common.css* and *dashboardAirLeft.css*, however in *chunk-common.css* and *dashboardAirLeft.css* all have *normalize.scss* code, like following:

[image]

And my production's Webpack config like this:

[image]

**My destination is to separate the common code from my page-name css file**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `loaderOptions` data property means that the files you import **will be imported into every single components `<style>` tag**. So each page-name css file will also import all three of the scss files you've defined. Instead, you probably want to import the common scss files only once in the `App.vue` component (or main entrypoint):

**App.vue**

```
<template>...</template>

<script>...</script>

<style lang="scss">
  @import "@/assets/styles/scss/normalize.scss"
  @import "@/assets/styles/scss/base-style.scss"
</style>
```

However, you do want the `variables-custom.scss` file imported into each page  though so that you have access to your scss variables in each component. So you should leave **only** `variables-custom.scss` in your `loaderOptions`:

**vue.config.js**

```
css: {
  loaderOptions: {
    sass: {
      data: "@import '@/assets/styles/scss/variables-custom.scss'"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I try your method and get my aim. What's more, I have another question related to webpack. Could you help me, please? [This is the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58740885/how-to-separate-a-specified-file-using-webpack-in-vue-cli-project)