# How to separate a specified file using webpack in vue-cli project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vue-cli-3, webpack-splitchunks

I have a config file (config.js), which depends on two files: local.js(for development environment) and deploy.js(for production environment). After `run serve` or `run build`, it will create some configurations rely on the environment. I used it like the following:

```
<template>
</template>
<script>
import config from '@/assets/scripts/config.js'
export default {
  data() {
     return {
       apiBasePath: config.apiBasePath
     }
  }
}
</script>
```

My config.js:

```
import local from '../../../config/local'
import deploy from '../../../config/deploy'
export default {
  apiBasePath:
    process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
      ? deploy.corsDomain + ':' + deploy.emergencyPort
      : local.corsDomain + ':' + local.emergencyPort,
  fileBasePath:
    process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
      ? deploy.corsDomain + ':' + deploy.emergencyPort
      : local.corsDomain + ':5000',
  dataBasePath:
    process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
      ? deploy.corsDomain + ':' + deploy.emergencyPort
      : 'http://localhost' + ':' + local.emergencyPort,
  vocApiPath:
    process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
      ? deploy.corsDomain + ':' + deploy.sharePort
      : local.corsDomain + ':' + local.sharePort,
  visualBasePath:
    process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
      ? deploy.corsDomain + ':' + deploy.simulatorPort
      : local.corsDomain + ':' + local.simulatorPort,
  spotBasePath:
    process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
      ? deploy.corsDomain + ':' + deploy.samplePort
      : local.corsDomain + ':' + local.samplePort,
  shareBasePath:
    process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
      ? deploy.corsDomain + ':' + deploy.sharePort
      : local.corsDomain + ':' + local.sharePort,
  envBasePath:
    process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
      ? deploy.corsDomain + ':' + deploy.envPort
      : local.corsDomain + ':' + local.envPort,
  ep360BasePath:
    process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
      ? deploy.corsDomain + ':' + deploy.ep360Port
      : local.corsDomain + ':' + local.ep360Port,
  defaultDivision: {
    province: deploy.defaultProvince ? deploy.defaultProvince : '浙江省',
    city: deploy.defaultCity ? deploy.defaultCity : '宁波市',
    area: deploy.defaultArea ? deploy.defaultArea : '鄞州区'
  }
}
```

But after buiding, these configurations will be insert in chunk-common scripts.
My destination is:
**Split this config file from my common chunk as a single one(suppose its name is config.[hash].js) and it will become a script tag insert in HTML when `run build`. After that, I can change some configurations in server and needn't rebuild my project when I set some wrong configurations**

**More Detail**: My project is a multiple-entries project, there is almost import the config.js in each entry. I tried the dynamic import as @Arunmozhi said, I can't get the configurations in the `data` function because of the `Promise` return although the *config chunk* is split. I'm trying to use `splitChunks` to solve my problems, but it didn't work.

```
optimization: {
  splitChunks: {
    cacheGroups: {
      myconfig: {
        test: module => {
          module
            .identifier()
            .split('/')
            .reduceRight(item => item)
            .indexOf('config') !== -1
        },
        name: 'myconfig',
        enforce: true,
        chunks: 'all',
        reuseExistingChunk: true,
        minChunks: 1,
        minSize: 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To have a separate script tag **without** going through the webpack processing, you should take it out of the `src` and move it to the `public` directory and add the script tag to the `index.html`. If you structure your config in such a way that it is available as a global object (for e.g., `document.myAppConfig`), then you can access the config values without having to do an `import`.

**Edit:** As commented, the config file that is shown is dependent on the BUILD process and can't be expected to be regenerated without rebuilding the project. However the closest one can get to achieving the flexibility of editing the configuration after building is to use the `import()` function instead of the ES6 `import config from "config.js"` module format.

If you can find a way to import the configuration like this

```js
config: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "config" */ "./config.js")
```

this would generate a separate chunk that you can later edit independently.

**CAVEAT:** This would create problems for the users due to web browsers caching resources.

Comment: My config.js depends on some environment variables, so it can't be moved to the `public` directory as a static file

Comment: In that case, it is a part of your build process and the expectation of editing that one file alone without rebuilding is impossible.

Comment: @sknight: Added an alternate method of generating a separate config file, which I would strongly discourage.

Comment: The data structure of this config file will not be changed even if be rebuilt. Certainly, I need to rebuild if I write the wrong logic code in this file. But if I write the wrong configuration such as `web port`, I needn't rebuild it. I only edit in server.

Comment: Thanks for your method, but I can't get the configurations in `data` function in Vue because of the `Promise` return.